# UIWebview memory problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview, ipad

In my App I have a large memory issue
I add UIScrollview with a viewController views dynamically when I need
and I properly remove the viewController while scrolling.
and in that viewController I placed a UIWebiew in IBOutlet and load webview
as

```
[m_objWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]]];
```

and release UIWebview in viewControllers dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {

 m_objWebView.delegate=nil;
 [m_objWebView stopLoading];
 [m_objWebView release];
 m_objWebView=nil;

 [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

 [super dealloc];
}
```

but after 5/6 minutes my app crashes after Memory Warning.

Now I change the code that I directly add uiwebview to uiscrollview and do lazy-loading of three webviews. now memory leak reduce but it still there. but now I have another problem that when user swipe fast there is a delay in loading web-content any way to solve this?

help me thanks in advance

Comment: How are you creating the web view? Why are you not releasing `view`?

Answer (score 2):

Removing subviews from an UIViewController's view in the dealloc is unnecessary. The view property and all its subviews will be automatically released as the owner (the UIViewController) is released. All you need to do is release any properties you have retained. Assuming that you have declared m_objWebView as
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *m_objWebView, then all you need is:

```
- (void)dealloc {

 m_objWebView.delegate=nil;
 [m_objWebView stopLoading];
 [m_objWebView release], m_objWebView=nil;

 [super dealloc];
}
```

So, I suggest you look into when and where you retain / release the viewController, that's where you may still be able to optimize things. As for the delay in loading web-content -- well, that's the downside of lazy-loading: lazy keeps your memory-consumption to a minimum but, as the term implies, it ain't fast.

Comment: thanks Elise van. Is there is any way to pre-load UIwebview? with the loacl content in document folder

Comment: As I wrote the answer, I was wondering the same thing. I guess if you know the url(s) in advance, then you could cache the view with NSKeyedArchiver/ NSKeyUnarchiver. But then you'd have to figure out when and how to check for new content. On the other hand, perhaps the WebView kit has methods that deal with exactly this problem -- I don't know enough about UIWebView, NSURL and its brethren to advise you on this. Good luck.